# Decrease image height when decreasing width

Tags: html, css

So.. My question is about responsive design.

I have a navbar of 20%, a body of 60% and a footer of 20%.

All good but when it comes to smaller devices. With decreasing the width, i don't want body to have 60%. What i want to know how to make so that when decreasing device width with every px, as well the height is decreasing every x dynamically.

Can you help me guys ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with `@media` queries in CSS? Also, it would be great if you included your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use vw instead of percent(%) as your unit for the height of the element you want to shrink when the page width shrinks. In your example, navbar with height 20% becomes height: 10vw (that was the equivalent height on MY screen. It may be different on yours - play with the vw value until it looks right.) Mine came out to navbar: 10vw, body: 36vw, and footer: 10vw.
-- OR -- 
It seemed like from your question that you only want the body to shrink, in that case, try something like navbar: 20%, body: 36vw, and footer: 20%.

Hope this helps.